# How to Detect IE7 After Upgrading to jQuery 1.9+

Tags: jquery

I understand that we're supposed to prefer "feature detection" to "version detection," but I've got a site that is explicitly NOT supported for IE7 (or earlier *shudder*).  I'd like to simply display a dialog when a user connects to the site using an unsupported browser.

Since jQuery 1.9+ has removed its functionality for detecting specific browsers, what is the best way for me to do a check for this "browser blacklist" . . . ?  It feels hacky to arbitrary choose some feature that is unsupported in IE7 and use that as the basis for presenting a "Sorry, Internet Explorer 7 and earlier are not supported" message . . .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var isLessThanIE8 = false;
</script>
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
    <script type="text/javascript">isLessThanIE8 = true;</script>
<![endif]-->
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (isLessThanIE8 === true) {
        alert('Get a new browser');
    }
</script>
```

Cross-browser compatible, never throws a javascript error, and not really "hacky".